# Post-Yosemite Rails install failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, homebrew, osx-yosemite

I recently upgraded to Yosemite and have since witnessed problems with my dev environment. I can't seem to install rails, which is something i noticed when I went to create a new rails project and it informed me it was not installed.

```
~  sudo gem install rails
```

> Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/user/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.1/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": dlopen(/Users/user/.rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13.1.0/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
>     Referenced from: /Users/user/.rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13.1.0/openssl.bundle
>     Reason: image not found - /Users/user/.rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/x86_64-darwin13.1.0/openssl.bundle (LoadError)
>   /Users/user/.rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/yaml.rb:4:in `':
>   It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).

Additionally Homebrew gave out as well..

```
~  brew update
```

> /usr/local/bin/brew:4: unknown regexp options - ll
>   /usr/local/bin/brew:7: `$(' is not allowed as a global variable name
>   /usr/local/bin/brew:7: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input
>   BREW_FILE_DIRECTORY=$(chdir "${0%/*}" && pwd -P)

Comment: Have you tried running `brew doctor`?

Comment: so I was able to fix the homebrew issue by doing a full uninstall/reinstall of it. Unfortunately, still no solution for the rails install issue

Comment: Another question: Are you using rbenv or rvm to install Ruby?

Comment: NEW UPDATE: I was able to get rails installed. unfortunately now whenever I try to do something with rails, I get the following error: 

$ rails new
No value provided for required arguments 'app_path'